# minimum of several columns ignoring zero and null

Tags: sql, teradata

In TeraData, is there a simple way to select the minimum of several columns (i.e. creating a computed column) whilst ignoring columns containing zeros and NULLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `LEAST` function, but it doesn't ignore NULLs, thus you have to apply some additional logic like

```
LEAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(col1,0), 999999)
     ,COALESCE(NULLIF(col2,0), 999999)
     ,COALESCE(NULLIF(col3,0), 999999))
```

For `99999` you should use a value higher than any existing. 
If all columns might be NULL or zero you must add a final

```
NULLIF(LEAST(....), 99999)
```

to return NULL in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Just learned about least. But would it not return zeros? Example: 1 2 3 0 => 0

Comment: Of course, I forgot about the zeroes, added `NULLIF`

Comment: OK ta. Will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can sort of use `least()`:

```
select least(col1, col2, col3)
```

This is tricky with `0`s and `NULL`s.  You don't specify the types of columns, but you can use `NULLIF()` and `COALESCE()` for positive numeric values:

```
select least( coalesce(nullif(col1, 0), 999999999),
              coalesce(nullif(col2, 0), 999999999),
              coalesce(nullif(col2, 0), 999999999)
            )
```

Of course, this returns the special value `999999999` if all values are `0` or `NULL`.